Is there a way to make the tangents actually follow the last curve segment direction?
The tangents are a little visualy rebel, idk mathematically why, but they form an angle between curve segments. Is there a way for them to actually follow the direction of the last curve segment perfectly using geo nodes?

Here I'm instancing arrows from an underlying curve. The arrows are representative of the curve tangent directions.
